# How to show Products attributes on blade file (color, size etc.) in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, laravel-blade

This is Ahmad Raza.

I'm working on E-commerce Project. I am trying to get product attributes on Product details page where user can select attributes before adding to cart.

**I have two color attributes of single product in my database table. But I want to show only one color in my select box.**

[image: Click to show image]

**Product Attributes Table**

```
 Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->string('sku');
            $table->string('size');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('stock');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Relation**

```
 public function attributes()
{
        return $this->hasmany('App\Models\ProductAttributes', 'product_id');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/view-product-details/{id}', [ShopController::class, 'view_product_details']);
```

**Function - Sending Attributes to blade file**

```
$product_attributes = ProductAttributes::where(['product_id' => $id])->get();
```

**Receiving Color Attributes in select box**

```
<select class="custom-select" selected id="inputGroupSelect01" name="color">
 @foreach ($product_attributes as $color)

   <option value="{{$color->color}}"name="color">
    {{$color->color}}
  </option>

 @endforeach
</select>
```

**My Output**

[image]

I know this is not looking fine. I want to show only one black color here, but I can't.

Please help me to figure out the problem and guide me how can I resolve this.

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: `selected` goes on `<option>` elements, not `<select>`. The `name` attribute on your `<option>`s is useless

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have made changes but my issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: because you have two entries for `black` color. so show options with more detail like `small-002 Black` and `medium-002 Black`

Comment: both `black` options are not same, its different size, price etc..

Comment: i understand. But i am not able to implement these changes in my code. Can you do that. plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two entries for black color. so show options with more detail like `small-002 Black` and `medium-002 Black`

Try with this code

```
<select class="custom-select" selected id="inputGroupSelect01" name="color">
    @foreach ($product_attributes as $color)
        <option value="{{ $color->id }}" name="color">
            {{$color->sku .' '.$color->color}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the select consists of only the color options you can use the `groupBy()` while retrieving the product attributes see the code below:

```php
$product_attributes = ProductAttributes::select("color")->where(['product_id' => $id])->groupBy("color")->get();
```

And then get the data the same as you did.

```html
<select class="custom-select" selected id="inputGroupSelect01" name="color">
 @foreach ($product_attributes as $color)

   <option value="{{$color->color}}"name="color">
    {{$color->color}}
  </option>

 @endforeach
</select>
```